# How to redirect urls?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

This is my main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("shop.urls")),
]
```

I want that any url entered by user will redirect to shop.urls and find there
like if the user enters **/index** it will search index in shop.urls not in main urls.

My shop.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('index', views.index),
]
```

[image]

Comment: You can see available patterns in image in that you've `/index` without ending with `/` so if you navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` it should display your page but since django appnds slash you've to enable [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting to disable that behaviour

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yes that's also true but appending `/` is a good practice.

Comment: Hello, @SunderamDubey I'm aware of that & that's why I've shared doc. link they've mentioned issue regarding not putting `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `/` at the end of route so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('index/', views.index),
]
```

Then enter the requested url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/`

Answer (score 1):

In main urls:

just give route name.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/', include("shop.urls")),
]
```

And this is your shop urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index),
]
```

After changing above code.

You can navigate like this in your browser:

```
localhost:8000/shop/index/
```

You will redirect to index page.

Comment: but i want without entering shop we will see index file